# Access the Host PC inside the VM? - Workstation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

Is there a way where I can access the Host PC inside the virtual machine I created? I'm using TightVNC to access the virtual machine I created (windows) and was wondering if I can access the host PC (Linux) to install TightVNC on it as well.

I'm working overseas and can't access the host PC physically.

Is there a way?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Let's get the terminology out of the way first:

The *host system* shall be the machine running VMWare Workstation. The virtualized system ("the virtual machine") shall be called the *guest system*. In this case, I assume your host system to be Linux-based, and the guest system to be running a Windows flavour, which has an already configured instance of TightVNC Server accepting connections from "the internet", over which you can login and get a Windows desktop.

If you do not have any way to access the host system already, there's likely a reason for that, and you would need to contact the responsible administrator to install and enable a way for you to login to the host system.

If you *are* the administrator of the Linux host system, then you already should have the ability to install additional software: In that case just pick a VNC server of your choice, and bind it to either

- the network interface connected to the internet, and directly connect to the Linux host's VNC server as you would to the guest system's server, or
- the network interface to which the guest system is connected, too, and connect to this interface's IP address from your VNC session running on the guest.

The latter is a bit silly, really, and the correct IP may be tricky to find. Generally, your guest systems will use a valid host IP address as their default gateway, which can be displayed by running

```
ipconfig
```

in a command prompt, and looking for the default gateway for your network device. The same IP address should work to connect to the VNC server running on the host system, if it has been correctly bound to this address/interface.

Debug logs go a long way in diagnosing problems, but if you do have root access on the Linux host system anyway, the "cleanest" alternative is setting up an SSL-enabled VNC server, and exposing it directly to the internet to cut out the Windows VM as a middleman.